# PostgreSQL: If I define 1-to-1 views for each of my tables and query only from my view layer, will the indexes of the underlying tables be used?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, database-indexes

I am using PostgreSQL and I want to create a layer of views on top of all the tables in my database schema. I will implement a 1-to-1 mapping of view to table, so these views will not have joins in them. The purpose is to provide a read-only abstraction so that I can change the underlying table structure of the database over time but control what is exposed through the views.

The question I have is when I start querying (SELECT statements only) using the views, including some complex joins and other complex query dynamics like aggregation/grouping, will PostgreSQL make use of the indexes on the underlying tables as if I was querying them directly?

I am starting with a PoC of this now. I don't have any results yet, but wanted to hear from other people's knowledge, experiences and opinions.

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the engine will use available indexes and optimize the code. It will basically replace the view with its definition and build the plan.

[Here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-performance-how-the-optimizer-handles-views) you can fine some example and test it further.